# Does sklearn.TimeSeriesSplit use any vectorized operations?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a pretty big dataset 5000X37. It is a time series dataset, and I was trying to do walk-forward validation. Using for loops, it takes about 350 minutes for 10 models to iteratively walk-forward validate. I wanted to vectorize this so that I could speed up the training. Does the TimeSeriesSplit implementation of sklearn internally vectorize the training or do I have to implement it from scratch?

Docs for sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html

The article I was consulting from sklearn walk forward validation: https://audhiaprilliant.medium.com/walk-forward-optimization-cross-validation-technique-for-time-series-data-61739f58f2c0

Comment: From the code (see `[source]`) and examples, `TimeSeriesSplit().split(x)` is a `generator`.  The docs has examples of how it is used - in a for loop.  For what it does I imagine it makes good use of `numpy` methods, but I haven't studied the code.  I don't understand what you mean by "internally vectorize the training".

Comment: This is what I mean by vectorization @hpaulj : https://towardsdatascience.com/vectorisation-how-to-speed-up-your-machine-learning-algorithm-by-x78-times-faster-e330df8c9b27